# How exactly is Typesafe's scala-logging more performant than other logging frameworks?

Tags: scala, logging, scala-logging

On the [Github](https://github.com/typesafehub/scala-logging) page it says:

> It's performant, because thanks to Scala macros the *check-enabled-idiom* is applied and the following code is generated:
>
> ```
> if (logger.isDebugEnabled) logger.debug(s"Some $expensive message!")
> ```

How is that more performant than, say, Play's logging?

In Play, it wraps the underlying logger with its own calls, and just checks if debug is enabled in regular code, no macro involved:

```
def debug(message: => String)(implicit mc: MarkerContext): Unit = {
  if (isDebugEnabled) {
    mc.marker match {
      case None => logger.debug(message)
      case Some(marker) => logger.debug(marker, message)
    }
  }
}
```

(Source code is [here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/9228109dcac2a75023187175a44bb15fd836e0e6/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/Logger.scala#L119-L126))

How is checking if debug is enabled via a macro makes it more performant?

Comment: where does it say that it is "more" performant than something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider a simpler method:

```
def debug(message: => String): Unit = {
  if (logger.isDebugEnabled) {
    logger.debug(message)
  }
}
```

Here, this method accepts a by-name parameter and invokes it only when debugging is enabled. Internally, all by-name parameters map to nullary functions, so this method is equivalent to the following one:

```
def debug(message: () => String): Unit = {
  if (logger.isDebugEnabled) {
    logger.debug(message())
  }
}
```

This means that **every time you invoke this method** in your code a **new function instance is created**. Maybe the compiler can optimize it sometimes, but definitely not always. In general, invoking methods with by-name calls require creating instances of function classes internally, and if you capture any variables, which is almost always:

```
logger.debug(s"Something interesting happened: $something. Message: $message")
```

then this function object, being a closure, would also contain references to these captured variables.

Compared to this, the macro-based method will be literally rewritten into the condition check and underlying logger invocation:

```
logger.debug(s"Something interesting happened: $something. Message: $message")
// gets rewritten to
if (logger.logger.isDebugEnabled) {
  logger.logger.debug(s"Something interesting happened: $something. Message: $message")
}
```

This way, no extra objects are created; the code would work as if you have written it out explicitly, except that you don't have to actually write this boilerplate.

Comment: As I understand, whether the string is call-by-name or not, as soon as it's passed to the `debug()` method, all the capture variables will be evaluated  regardless to it being a macro or not. Same goes to the nullary function. The macro merely generates the wrapping if-statement. It doesn't eliminate any of those things.

I still don't get it

Comment: If the OPs example used a `String` instead of a call by name value both the macro use and the regular if check would be identical.

Comment: @OriPopowski, no, the macro does eliminate the imminent construction of a `Function0` object, which is *always* constructed for by-name arguments. With macro, you simply do not have it at all because it would rewrite the method call into an `if` statement.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov it is true, but logging libraries do not accept just `String`s for a reason; see my comment to your answer. Even Java libraries usually allow passing a formatted string with a set of arguments instead of forcing the user to do the string construction.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev So maybe I did not understand it correctly. The macro is going to be *inlined* into the application code? I imagined the resulting byte code would still have a call to a method.

Comment: @OriPopowski, also, the idea is that with the by-name parameter, you only evaluate it if the `isDebugEnabled` condition yields `true`; if debug logging is disabled, then the by-name parameter is never evaluated. However, its underlying `Function0` instance still has to be created; that's why macros a little bit more efficient.

Comment: See my answer to your comment to understand what I meant :)

Comment: @OriPopowski absolutely, the macro is going to be inlined. That's the purpose of macros, after all.

Comment: I understand what you mean now! I didn't think about how the macro replaces the method call at all. Thanks!